# Retrieving memory data with non-canonical-address causes SIGSEGV rather than SIGBUS

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, bus-error

I can not produce a "Bus error" with the following assembly code. Here the memory address I use is not a legal "canonical-address". So, how can I trigger that error?

I was running this snippet of code under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with NASM 2.14.02, but it results in a SIGSEGV segmentation fault on the load, not SIGBUS.

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    mov rax, [qword 0x11223344557788]
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Corresponding X86-64 assembly code after compiling:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:   48 a1 88 77 55 44 33    movabs 0x11223344557788,%rax
  401007:   22 11 00 
  40100a:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  40100f:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
  401012:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: You're running this under Linux, right?  Please tag if so.

Comment: Have you tried using the `kill` system call to deliver a `SIGBUS` to yourself?

Comment: It seems that Linux chooses to deliver SIGSEGV for a non-canonical address.

You can get SIGBUS by reading from a `mmap`ed page if the underlying file has been truncated, and you can of course use asm to make the system call to make that happen.  Or of course [`raise(SIGBUS)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html#NOTES).  I think there is some kind of x86 exception (other than that special case of #PF) that the OS handles by delivering SIGBUS; possibly alignment-checking `#AC`, if you had a kernel module enable the AC flag?

Comment: If you're looking for a HW-exception specific way, please make your title and/or question body more specific / explicit about that.  Otherwise as @fuz points out, `kill(getpid(), SIGBUS)` or `tgkill` is a trivial answer.

Comment: @fuz: nope, I just want to see how the OS reacts to this kind of data retrieving operation with a non-canonical-address.

Comment: That's a different question.  I had kind of expected SIGBUS for a non-canonical address, that would be logical, but the SIGSEGV we actually get also makes logical sense.  You don't have that memory mapped.  The fact that you *couldn't* map that address might mean you'd get `-EINVAL` from mmap if you tried with `MAP_FIXED`.

Comment: By the way, the address you are using is canonical on Ice Lake CPUs.

Comment: @Kit.: Only if you enabled PML5, though, right?  Or would it `#PF` instead of `#GP` even if the kernel hadn't enabled that bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you review the Instruction Set Architecture manual for the [MOV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) instruction you would find that accessing a non-canonical address yields a `#GP(0)` General Protection Fault:

[image]

Linux maps all `#GP` exceptions to SIGSEGV signal (Segmentation Fault). However, in Linux there is a way for a non-canonical address to cause a *Bus Error* and that is by getting the processor to raise an `#SS` (Stack Segment) exception. Linux maps `#SS` exceptions to the SIGBUS signal. Setting the stack pointer to a non-canonical address and then performing a stack related operation will produce such an exception.

This code should produce a *Bus Error*:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    mov rsp, 0x8000000000000000 ; Set RSP to a non-canonical address
    push rax                    ; Pushing value on stack should produce BUS ERROR
```

One other way of producing a Bus Error on Linux is to raise an `#AC` (Alignment Check) exception. If you write ring 3 (user) code that enables the Alignment Check bit (bit 18) in [RFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) and do an unaligned memory access you should also receive a SIGBUS signal. This code should produce a *Bus Error*:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    pushf                      ; Put current RFLAGS on the stack
    or dword [rsp], 1<<18      ; Enable bit 18 (Alignment Check) of the
                               ;     RFLAGS value saved on stack
    popf                       ; Pop new RFLAGS flags value into the RFLAGS register
    mov eax, [rsp + 1]         ; Move a DWORD value from unaligned address
                               ;     Should produce a BUS ERROR
```

Comment: @Joseph, although your edit works mine does as well.With the AC bit enabled all memory accesses are checked whether on a stack operation or not.

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to make it more obvious that the signal is from the misalignment and not from trying to read an unmapped page.